# Определить ориентацию экрана

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, (ответом да или нет), можно ли определить ориентацию экрана при его поворотах, если в манифесте прописано:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Если да, то каким методом?

Вот этот метод у меня не работает, всегда пишет ту ориентацию, с которой открывал:

```
private String getScreenOrientation(){
    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        return "Портретная ориентация";
    else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        return "Альбомная ориентация";
    else
        return "";
}
```

Вызов:

```
//отследить поворот экрана
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    Toast.makeText(this, getScreenOrientation(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Обычно для этого используют:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

Выдаёт  `Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT` или `Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE`.

Если нужен угол поворота:

```
int rotate = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
switch (rotate) {
    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
        return "Не поворачивали";
    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
        return "Повернули на 90 градусов по часовой стрелке";
    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
        return "Повернули на 180 градусов";
    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
        return "Повернули на 90 градусов против часовой стрелки";
    default:
        return "Не понятно";
}
```

Подробнее можете посмотреть [здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/orientation.php).

Comment: Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT или Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE у меня не работает, я в вопросе дописал как у меня происходит.

Comment: Самое интересное, что углы определяет нормально, наверно по ним буду делать. В проекте очень много всяких загрузок и разметок, кол-во view приблизительно 350 шт, и все это на одной активити со скрытыми контейнерам(окнами), подключенными через include. Может из за такого количества не успевает срабатывать? Так как создал голый проект, и там все работает.

Answer (score 1):

Не работает потому что не был вызван метод родителя до проверки - поэтому конфигурация не обновилась и вы получаете старую.

```
//отследить поворот экрана
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Toast.makeText(this, getScreenOrientation(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Ну и, собственно, новая конфигурация приходит аргументом метода и получить новую ориентацию можно из него:

```
//отследить поворот экрана
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    Toast.makeText(this, getScreenOrientation(newConfig), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

private String getScreenOrientation(Configuration сonfig){
    if(сonfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        return "Портретная ориентация";
    else if (сonfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        return "Альбомная ориентация";
    else
        return "";
}
```

Comment: Я не знаю почему, но на xiaomi Mi A1 на чистом андроид 7 именно в моем приложении у меня ориентация не определяется во время поворота экрана.. На самсунге j1 mini(андроид 5) и на Homtom HT17 pro(андроид 6) это же приложение работает нормально. Единственное, что правильно работает из выше примеров на mi a1, это углы из кода выше от Streletz, по ним и определяю. Кстати на смартфоне Mi a1 метод onConfigurationChanged вызывается два раза подряд, на других смартфонах один раз, с чем связано не знаю.

Comment: Посмотрите под отладчиком содержимое `newConfig` или в лог его выведите. Без никакой информации нельзя сказать что с ним не так.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
public int getScreenOrientation()
{
    Display getOrient = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED;
    if(getOrient.getWidth()==getOrient.getHeight()){
        orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE;
    } else{ 
        if(getOrient.getWidth() < getOrient.getHeight()){
            orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        }else { 
             orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        }
    }
    return orientation;
}
```

Используйте:

```
if (orientation==1)        // 1 for Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
{                          // 2 for Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
   //your code             // 0 for Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE
}
```

Comment: Не нужно использовать 1, 2 и 0, а нужно использовать именно те имена констант, которые вы написали в комментариях. Они для того и созданы.