# Как узнать что панель навигации находится с левой стороны экрана?

Tags: android, android-studio, navigationbar

подскажите пожалуйста.
Есть ли возможность программно узнать, находится ли нижняя навигационная панель **с лева в альбомной ориентации**?
При запуске приложения на смартфоне.

Comment: Думаю это должно помочь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1021672/11515

Comment: @woesss Спасибо это то что было необходимо. Заметил интересную особенность. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1133577/При-смене-ориентации-не-происходит-пересоздание-активности