# При смене ориентации не происходит пересоздание активности

Tags: android, activity, orientation

Тестирую приложение на устройстве MI A2.

При разработке заметил такую особенность.

Если из портретной ориентации, повернуть устройство в лево на 90градусов, переведу его в альбомную ориентацию, а затем еще в лево на 180грудусов, опять получая альбомную ориентацию.

Так вот при втором повороте не происходит пересоздание активности.

Даже если в манифесте я указываю для своей активности:
`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"`

При втором повороте не происходит вызова метода `onConfigurationChanged()`

Можно ли как-то отследить такое вращение устройства?

Comment: OnResume вызывается при перерисовке

Comment: @DrMcSheep, Прочитав описание к вопросу, можно увидеть, что при втором повороте устройства, активность не пересоздается и соответственно не один из методов жизненного цикла активности, не запускается.

Comment: @Hromlisp, Вы удивитесь, но активность не пересоздаётся и при первом повороте. Она перерисовывается. Правильно заданный вопрос содержит в себе половину ответа.
Не экономьте буквы.

Comment: @DrMcSheen  прошу прощение, я и правда могу не точно называть некоторые термины. При первом повороте описанном выше, происходит перерисовка активности и запуск  соответствующих методов из жизненного цикла активности. А при втором повороте именно таком который описан в вопросе, эти методы не запускаются и перерисовки активности не происходит. Может вы знаете причины такого поведения?